# Trouble Installing TopoJSON in FreeBSD 8.4

Tags: npm, topojson

The same as [Maura](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1951366/maura), I'm also working on [Mike Bostock's Map](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/). But instead of installing GDAL, I have trouble in installing TopoJSON. Here is my command (I'm on a FreeBSD 8.4):

```
root@myvirtualbox:~ # npm install -g topojson
```

And finally I get the following error in [delayed-stream](https://npmjs.org/package/delayed-stream) package installation:

```
...
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Please help me and thank's for your attention.

=============== Please notice that I have already found the answer ============
Here is the solution for my trouble in installing TopoJSON on FreeBSD 8.4:

1. Make sure that the installed Node.js is the STABLE version, not the DEVEL version. (I previously installed the Node.js via ports, `/usr/ports/www/node-devel`, then I deinstalled it, and finally I switched to `/usr/ports/www/node`)
2. Execute the NPM command as superuser when installing TopoJSON.

   `root@myvirtualbox:~ # npm install -g topojson`
3. Have fun!

Comment: have you already tried with sudo prefix?

Comment: (Please apologize me for a late response) -- Yes I have, but the error still exists. But at the other hand, when I try it on FreeBSD 8.3 + Node 0.8.4 + NPM 1.1.45, everything runs smoothly. Is it NPM or Node issue, anyway?

Comment: i would guess it's npm, since it gives you back a npm ERR

Comment: After a lot of attempt, finally it's about my node.js version, which needs to be stable -- not -devel version. Moreover, it's also important to manually clear the cache with `# npm cache clear`. Anyway, to @tomtomtom: thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: you're welcome, sorry i couldn't be of any more help